# After apply l'Hopital's rule, when one gets infinity

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to solve this problem :

$$ \mathbb{P}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{p_{H}+(1-p_{H})(1-x)^{t}}{p_{H}+(1-p_{H})(1-x)^{t-x}}-\frac{p_{L}+(1-p_{L})(1-x)^{t}}{p_{L}+(1-p_{L})(1-x)^{t-x}}}{x} $$

where $0<p_{L}<p_{H}<1$ and $0<t<\infty$.

Both denominator and nominator goes to 0, so I thought of applying l'Hopital's rule.

As the first step, I got the following :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{d\bigg{(}\frac{p_{H}+(1-p_{H})(1-x)^{t}}{p_{H}+(1-p_{H})(1-x)^{t-x}}\bigg{)}}{dx} = 0$$

using $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{d(1-x)^{t-x}}{dx}= -t$. The same calculation applies to the case of $p_{L}$. Therefore, I concluded that $\mathbb{P}=0$.

However, I feel something is going wrong, as $\mathbb{P}$ in my original problem represents Bayesian updating form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=p_H$ and $b=p_L$; so the numerator of the expression is
$$A=\frac{a+(1-a) (1-x)^t}{a+(1-a) (1-x)^{t-x}}-\frac{b+(1-b) (1-x)^t}{b+(1-b)
   (1-x)^{t-x}}$$ Using Taylor expansion around $x=0$
$$(1-x)^k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{k}{n} x^n$$ Use it for a very few terms and continue with the long division to obtain
$$\frac{a+(1-a) (1-x)^t}{a+(1-a) (1-x)^{t-x}}=1+(a-1) x^2-\frac{1}{2} (a-1) (2 a t-1)x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ that is to say
$$A=(a-b)x^2+O\left(x^3\right) \implies \mathbb{P}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac A x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}[(a-b)x]=0 $$ which is what you found using L'Hospital.

Are you sure that the denominator is not $x^2$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much leaving this answer. I tried to figure out if there is something I am missing, but I think I have trouble in understanding changing from discrete-time signal to continuous-time. I will post a new question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398721/change-discrete-time-bayesian-updating-to-continuous-time-for-this-case